# Select Distinct Count Question

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a question regarding LINQ to SQL. I would like to write the following query in LINQ:

```
SELECT DISTINCT([Column]),
       COUNT([Column]) as [Count]
FROM [Table]
```

Can I do this in 1 query? Or do I have to initially select my distinct columns, and then for each select the count? That seems very clumsy and heavy (n-squared).

Comment: BTW, it's called "LINQ to SQL" not "LINQ SQL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query isn't legal, as you're using an aggregate (`COUNT`) without grouping on the column that you're selecting.

What you want is something like this:

```
select [Column], Count([Column]) as [Count] from [Table] group by [Column]
```

That's easily expressed in LINQ to SQL.

```
from x in context.Table 
group x by x.Column into grp
select new { Column = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() }
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I had forgotten about the group by.. What about the DISTINCT? Do I need to specify it?

Comment: @Steve: Not if you're grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from r in table
group r by r.Something into g
select new { Something = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```